# passing json object from php to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json, node.js

In PHP, I have a JSON object like so (even here not sure if its correctly formatted and if I'm passing it correctly):

```
$someJSONObject = '{token:"randomtoken",signature:"signature"};
```

and encode it before passing the response:

```
$response['code'] = 1;
$response['status'] = $api_response_code[ $response['code'] ]['HTTP Response'];
$response['data'] = $someJSONObject;

my_response($_GET['format'], $response);  //json_encode($response)
```

then in my JS I receive it in string format like this:

```
{ code:1,
  status:200,
  data: '"{token:\\"randomtoken\\", signature:\\"signature\\"}"' }
```

I parse it into an object:

```
phpObj = JSON.parse(body);
```

so I can access 'data':

```
dataObj = phpObj.data;
```

which gives me the result as a string:

```
{token:\"randomtoken\", signature:\"signature\"}  //console.log(dataObj)
```

it's here where I lose my way and not able to access 'token' getting an undefined:

```
console.log('token: ' + dataObj.token)    //token:undefined
```

I realize I'm trying to dot into a string, so I must be doing something wrong at this last step. However, even if I try to use JSON.parse or JSON.stringify it still doesn't seem to help and gives me an 'undefined'.

```
dataObj = JSON.parse(phpObj.data);
console.log(typeof(dataObj);            //string
console.log(dataObj);                   //"\"{token:\\\"randomtoken\\\", signature:\\\"signature\\\"}\""
console.log(dataObj.token);             //token: undefined
```

or

```
 dataObj = JSON.stringify(phpObj.data);
 console.log(typeof(dataObj));          //string
 console.log(dataObj);                  //"\"{token:\\\"randomtoken\\\", signature:\\\"signature\\\"}\""
 console.log(dataObj.token);            //token: undefined
```

Any help/feedback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should NOT be embedding json-in-json. It's rather pointless. Deal with a purely NATIVE data structure, e.g.

```
$response = array(
   'code' => 1,
   'status' => xxx,
   'data' => array
         'token' => 'randomtoken',
         etc...
   )
);
```

And then encode that:

```
echo json_encode($response);
```

The JS side will decode that back into a native JS structure, and then you have, simply:

```
alert(response.data.token);
```

with no extra decoding steps, no worries about escaping quotes, etc...

Comment: Time and time again people keep trying to encode their own JSON when PHP has a function for it. I would like to know if you have a theory as to why this is the case all too often? Am I missing something, are there cases where `json_encode()` isn't good enough and I am simply the noob?

Comment: Thank you, Marc B. I changed:

Comment: Thank you, Marc B. I changed how I constructed the JSON object on the PHP to how you suggested and only initially parse the response with no extra decoding step. MonkeyZeus - I don't use PHP and it was obviously an error on my part with regard to how I handled JSON.

Answer (score 1):

First, this is not valid JSON:

```
 $someJSONObject = '{token:"randomtoken",signature:"signature"};
```

You need to enclose the keys in `"`. Better still, let PHP do it:

```
$someJSONObject = json_encode(array(
    'token' => 'randomtoken',
    'signature' = 'signature'
));
```

The really odd thing you're doing, however, is attempting to include a string of JSON in another string of JSON. This is, to put it mildly, confusing.

Instead, pass the data to `my_response` as an array, and let `json_encode` encode the whole lot.

```
$someJSONObject = array(
    'token' => 'randomtoken',
    'signature' = 'signature'
);
my_response($_GET['format'], $response);
```

In your Javascript, you should then be able to do `phpObj.data.token`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, lonesomeday. I actually meant to have the keys enclosed in quotes for the code I shared, but in my flustered/rush state shared the wrong code...I credit Marc B since his came in first, but appreciate your response....I tried manipulating the JSON object in the browser console and it seem to work the other way. Anyhow, thanks.

Comment: @DevPer No problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

I have a code similar but, my json looks like this

```
{ "token" [ "token": randomtoken, "signature": signature] }
```

then I manipulate like this:

```
var datos = JSON.parse(JSON);      
    for(var something in datos){
      var objeto = datos[something];
      alert('token: ' + objeto.token);
    }
```

sorry my bad english

Comment: Is this a question or an answer?